# Upgrade Maven1.x application to Maven3.0.x

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I've old application running on Java4 and Maven 1. I compiled this application to Java 8 but to run this application I want to convert it to support Maven 3.0.x. Can anyone please help how can I directly upgrade Maven 1 application to Maven 3?
Your suggestion would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maven 1 is quite different from Maven 3, so I doubt you will find an automated way to translate the Maven 1 project descriptor files in Maven 3, that will be more efficient than just writing from scratch your Maven 3 POM.

Comment: Upgrade directly to Maven 3.3.9 or 3.5.0 and not to 3.0.5 ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Maven 3 is backwards compatible with Maven 2.

To migrate from Maven 1 to Maven 2, a guide can be found [here](http://takari.io/maven-3.3.1/guides/mini/guide-m1-m2.html)

Comment: I don't think migrating Maven 1 makes sense.  That ought to be a clean sheet restart.  Blow away your local .m2, install Maven 3, and put together a pom.xml in the new project.  The bigger issue will be the upgrade from JDK 4 to 8.

Comment: @duffymo Yeah I understand there is huge gap in JDK 4 and JDK 8 but for that I first need to let it support Maven3 so that I can be able to atleast run the source code in JDK8 and can see chances of errors could occur.

Comment: Maven should be a separate matter.  Install new Maven, blow away the old .m2, check your pom.xml, and see what dependencies it brings in.  From that point forward you have a JDK 8 conversion and currency problem.  My guess is that you'll have a lot of out of date dependencies that you'll need to clean up.

Comment: @duffymo I created a new MavenTest project in Maven3 and copied the same dependencies of my application to check if any jar is uncompatible, I run 'Maven Clean' & 'Maven install' command and all the jars of same version are downloaded to application.

Comment: Excellent!  How's that work out?  You've upgraded to JDK 8 as well?

Comment: well, I'm not done because I have only checked my project to eclipse neon set jdk to 8 and configure maven3 to eclipse that's it. To run my project I need to follow maven 3 structure which I want to understand how to start? all my source code is as it is, I've not done any changes to source code I want to check which jars of my application are unsupported or incompatible at run time with jdk8

Comment: What do you mean with "understanding the maven 3 structure"? I guess you're not talking about the project structure.

Comment: I'm talking about project structure only. As changing maven changes structure of project.

Comment: i.e standard directory layout followed by Maven.